# Entity Framework doesn't save

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am trying to update my table `Bareme` but I get an exception about my unique key  `(Categorie , Section)`, but as seen here am updating only my salary if the object does exist, and I've verified by "DEBUG" that none of the inserted objects is duplicated

The inner exception says :

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'IX_Bareme'. Cannot insert duplicate key in    object 'dbo.Bareme'.\r\nThe statement has been
>   terminated.

Code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= sl_cat.Value; i++)
            for (int j = 1; j <= sl_sec.Value; j++)
            {

                Bareme brm = db.Entities.Baremes.Select(X => X).Where(X => X.Section == j && X.Categorie == i).FirstOrDefault();
                if (brm != null)
                    db.Entities.Baremes.DeleteObject(brm);

                brm = new Bareme();
                brm.Categorie = i;
                brm.Section = j;
                brm.Salaire = dt.Rows[j - 1][i.ToString()].ToString().ToDecimal();
                db.Entities.Baremes.AddObject(brm);
            }

        try
        {
            db.Entities.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: when you do your AddObhject() all rows will have same ID BRM. Is that ok ???

Comment: even if i updated my code like this it doesn't work even if i add `SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave` of @HatSoft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the `SaveChanges Method` with  `SaveOptions` for `DetectChangesBeforeSave`

**Example**

```
db.Entities.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);
```

Comment: @SéddikLaraba what exception did you get

Comment: `an error occured while updating the entity, see inner exception for more details` the inner exception is written in the question

Comment: sorry i relized the i've forgotten some changes before, its working greatly now, thank you

Comment: @SéddikLaraba no problem mate and I am glad its fixed for you